# ping - does it increase load to the network?

Tags: ping

I find a network in an organisation too slow. A specific internal site goes down frequently and i wanted to understand the trend. I am doing ping test to that site for every 5 min and built that as a jenkins job. 
Now my question is does that put load to the network. I read it is not a good approach and do we have alternatives to test such scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume a typical ping packet and reply is 84 bytes each, and you are pinging once a second. That is 2 * 86,400 * 84 bytes or about 13 megabytes of traffic per day. Or about ~1.2kilobit/s. So unless you are running on a 9600 baud modem, you probably can handle it.